# Nesting multiple while loops - CS50 greedy.c less

Tags: c, cs50, greedy

I am very new to programming and having some difficulty in understanding how `while` loops can be used in conjunction with one another.

You can see from my code that I can get the coin count to increase, but I feel that `while` loops should be used as opposed to `do-while` loops to count down the change total line by line.

Maybe I am making it more complicated than required but are multiple `while` loops the best way to count down the change value?

Any hints or tips greatly appreciated thanks!

```
int main(void)
{
printf("O hai! ");

float change;

do
{
    printf("How much change is owed?\n");
    change = get_float();
}
while (change <= 0);

int n = (change * 100);     // multiply change by 100 to get int in cents(n)

int coin = 0;               // new int to represent amount of coins


coin++;
int quart = n - 25;     // subtract 25c from n

coin++;
int dime = quart - 10;  // subtract 10c from quart

coin++;
int nick = dime - 5;    // and so on

coin++;
int penny = nick - 1;   // and so on

penny = 0;              // and this is only here because I had an unused int (penny)


printf("%i\n", coin);
}
```

Comment: this is coin changing problem... you should really visit your TA for your coursework issues...

Comment: Are you taking this class on edX? If so, have you tried their forum? I think if you want to use the biggest coins possible you would loop through and keep removing quarters until you had less than 25 cents left, etc. Without using a loop it looks like you are just removing one of each coin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while loop works fine. You will want to make it more than 0 though, instead of less than or equal like you currently have, also, you don't need to define quarter/dime and all that, you could use if statements, such as if (cents left is more than coin value) than coins -= (this is the way to decrease every time it comes across) value you are subtracting. Try making these changes and I can help you more from there

Comment: Thanks @Joel Banks, appreciate the help.  I am implementing your suggestion now and will repost my outcome.

Comment: Forgive my formatting if incorrect, still learning.

Implemented some changes, all appears to be working correctly when I test, but check50 is coming back with:

`:) greedy exists

:) greedy compiles

:( input of 0.41 yields output of 4
    did not find "4\n"
:) input of 0.01 yields output of 1
:( input of 0.15 yields output of 2
    expected "2\n", not "15\n32767\n"
:( input of 1.6 yields output of 7
    did not find "7\n"
:( input of 23 yields output of 92
    did not find "92\n"
:( input of 4.2 yields output of 18
    timed out while waiting for program to exit`

Comment: New code:

[link](https://gist.github.com/mgf82/5986fc29c4c36051ca252d623dbf661d)

Comment: @Gus Try using a float instead of an int for x, and then rounding it down. Sometimes the computer interprets a number such as 41, as 41.0000000236813 or something like this, and this bit left over isn't being solved.